# EmEditorマクロで基本ツールバーの表示状態を取得したい

Tags: emeditor

特別ツールバーの場合は`QueryStatusByID(nID)`でチェック可能ですが、基本ツールバーの場合`editor.QueryStatusByID(EEID_TOOLBAR1 + n) & eeStatusLatched`は常に`0`を返します。
マクロリファレンスの[QueryStatusByIDの項](http://www.emeditor.org/ja/macro_editor_editor_querystatusbyid.html)で「すべてのコマンドが利用できないことがあります」との記述がありますので、これはサポート対象外ということだと認識しています。
ですので、他の手段でツールバーの表示状態を取得する方法が何かあればご教示いただきたく存じます。

EmEditor version 21.6.1 / Windows10 21H1(64bit)

なお、この質問の目的は『EmEditor起動・ウィンドウ表示時に特定のツールバーを非表示で開きたい（ツールバー表示状態を記憶してほしくない）』というもので、ウィンドウ作成時のイベントマクロでそれを実現していたのですが、ver21.4から並べ替えツールバーが基本ツールバー扱いになり対処不能、という経緯です。
表示のトグルではなく表示/非表示だけのコマンドがあれば解決できなくもないですが、状態取得ができた方がいいだろうと思いますので……

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本来は、`editor.QueryStatusByID(EEID_TOOLBAR1 + n) & eeStatusLatched` で正しく動作するはずなのですが、不具合がありました。Version 21.6.908 以降では修正します。

Comment: 最新ベータ版（21.6.908）で動作を確認しました。対応ありがとうございました。